# How do I find the volume of solids of revolution between 2 lines

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

I am very confused how to go about this problem:

```
Consider the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given 
curves about the x-axis:

y = 9 - 25x^2 , y = 0

Find the volume V of this solid.
```

I tried to do

```
integral from 0 to 9(pi(9 - 25x^2)^2)
```

but that doesnt seem to work out correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the format, this is my first post here

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. One issue: the function intersects $y=0$ when $x= \pm \frac 35$, not when $x=0$ and $x=9$.

So then we have $$\int_{-3/5}^{3/5} \pi (9 - 25x^2)^2 dx$$